# Should we merge [cookware] into [equipment]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I just noticed that we're starting to accumulate a fair number of questions tagged [cookware](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookware).  To me, this is a fairly ambiguous and trivial subset of [equipment](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment), especially considering that many "cookware" items can easily be used for baking or other types of food prep.

What does everybody think?  Any reason why these *shouldn't* be synonyms?

Comment: I think of cookware as pots, pans, tins, etc.  Equipment covers my mixer, food processor, etc.  Is this not common?

Comment: @justkt: Pans and tins might also be considered bakeware.  And what about something like a mixing bowl, or a pizza stone, which category does that go into?  I do understand that "cookware" does not mean the same thing as "equipment", I just don't think it's a tag we particularly need, and certainly not one that's actually been used in every question about cookware, which severely limits its usefulness.  Likewise, we don't see an `[appliances]` tag being used in every question about mixers or food processors.

Comment: Seems ok with me. Otherwise where do you stop?  Cutlery?

Comment: @Sam: I was thinking we could have questions tagged `[equipment]` `[dinnerware]` `[cutlery]` `[forks]` `[those-long-forks-people-use-to-scratch-their-butts]`.

Comment: agree with justkt. maybe the distinction is totally inanimate vs. mechanical?